# Bootstrap grid pull/push rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive bootstrap grid which I want to be shown in a different order depending on the device width.

sm or lower:

```
--------------
|      1     |
--------------
|      2     |
--------------
|      3     |
--------------
|      4     |
--------------
|      5     |
--------------
|      6     |
--------------
|      7     |
--------------
```

md or higher:

```
-------------
| 2 | 4 | 6 |
-------------
|     1     |
-------------
| 3 | 5 | 7 |
-------------
```

My problem is that col-pull and col-push only moves the column to the sides, not up and down.

This is what I have so far:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">6</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">7</div>
  </div>
```

, which displays correctly in small displays but on big ones it displays as the following:

```
-------------
|     1     |
-------------
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
-------------
| 6 | 5 | 7 |
-------------
```

I would need to swap first and second rows, and swap the column 3 with column 6. How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You may not have to duplicate all elements, just the ones you want to hide/show.  Something along the lines of:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 visible-xs">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">5</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0b80L3a2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is cheating, and duplicates your html markup, but here's how I handle these:

```
<div class="col-xs-visible">
    <!-- Your mobile version here -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">5</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">7</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-hidden">
    <!-- Your non-mobile version here -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">6</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I should duplicate my entire 7 cols, one for mobile and one for desktop? This way I wouldn't even need to use bootstrap at all, it is so ugly :(

Comment: agree, that's why I put my disclaimer on there :)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the given answers, I found my way around this with this code:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 only-mobile">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 only-mobile">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 no-mobile">6</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 no-mobile">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 no-mobile">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 only-mobile">6</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">7</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.no-mobile{
  display: block;
}
.only-mobile{
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:992px){
  .no-mobile{
    display: none;
  }
  .only-mobile{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are bootstrap classes for this: `visible-xs` and `hidden-xs` (and `*-sm`, `*-md` and `*-lg`). You should use these classes.

Comment: Why should I use those?

Comment: 1) because it's already build in 2) if you change your width for `xs`, `sm` and so on, the classes will adept the new values automatically 3) with bootstrap, always avoid specifying `media-screen and (x)` rules by hand. The breakpoints should be configured by the less (or sass) files within bootstrap.