# How to change bootstrap colum order on responsive for full grid?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know how to change bootstrap column order on responsive using `col-push` and `col-pull` but I couldn't achieve this with full grid (col-xs-12,col-sm-12). so what I want to do is you can see in below image

[image]

and my code

```css
#sidebar{
  background:lightblue;
}
#content{
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<main id="site-content" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <aside id="sidebar" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <h1>Sidebar</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos a sed, quidem corporis nam ut recusandae aliquid, fugiat, earum eveniet porro aliquam quod.</p>
    </aside>
    <div id="content" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <h2>Hi I'm a title of this container</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem dolore, quos corrupti soluta vel necessitatibus quibusdam, dolor, quae sed quod cum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm talking about for full grid col-xs-12 for example..and I guess this is different question

Comment: This question has been answered many times. Simply think mobile first! Place your B div above in your html and then apply pull-push.

Comment: make BA the order in the html file, use float right for the web view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap grid pull/push rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788846/bootstrap-grid-pull-push-rows)

Comment: please read carefully I'm talking on mobile for the full grid (12) I know how will I order them but I want to change order only on responsive so I can order on desktop to see same result on mobile.

Comment: so you are not looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nxtjr39b/23/)?

Comment: no I'm looking for this if you check code it must be full grid (12):https://jsfiddle.net/9yb5mp3w/

Answer (score 0):

switch the order in the html file, use float right for the web view

```css
#sidebar{
  background:lightblue;
  float:right;
}
#content{
  background:lightgreen;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<main id="site-content" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div id="content" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <h2>Hi I'm a title of this container</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem dolore, quos corrupti soluta vel necessitatibus quibusdam, dolor, quae sed quod cum.</p>
    </div>
    <aside id="sidebar" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <h1>Sidebar</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos a sed, quidem corporis nam ut recusandae aliquid, fugiat, earum eveniet porro aliquam quod.</p>
    </aside>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```